# having a hard time printing new line in assembly language

Tags: assembly, newline, dos, x86-16

newbie here, just started learning about assembly language and i couldn't print a new line for some reason idk what i did wrong, i also tried trying some of the answers i found in here but still not working, okay well here's the code

```
.model small
.stack 0100h
.data
   a db "name $"
   b db "year $"
   c db "school name $"
   d db "phone number $"
   
.code
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov ah, 09h
    mov dx, offset a
    int 21h     
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h
    
    mov dx, offset b
    int 21h
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h 
    
    mov dx, offset c
    int 21h 
    
    mov dl, 0ah
    int 21h
    mov dl, 0dh
    int 21h
    
    mov dx, offset d
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h 

end
```

Comment: You are missing the function passed in AL before your interrupt call. So add a `mov ah,02h` before every `mov dl, ... ; int 21h`.

Comment: Alternatively you can append CR+LF to each of your prompts: `a db "name ",0ah,0dh,"$"`.

Answer (score 2):

In DOS `int 21h` with `AH`=9 prints a `$` terminated string pointed to by `DS:DX`, it has no ability to determine that you intend print the character loaded into `DL` as registers do not remember the type of value loaded into them, unlike some other languages.

You can use `int 21h` with `AH`=2 to print individual characters, or you can add the newlines to the `$` terminated strings.